# Type 'Promise<void>' is missing the following properties from type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, promise

I am not quite understanding the following error:

```
Type 'Promise<void>' is missing the following properties from type 'InventoryModel[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 28 more.  TS2740
```

I have the following functional component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Grid, TextField } from "@material-ui/core";
import InventoryService from "../services/Inventory";
import InventoryModel from "../Models/Inventory";
import { isThisTypeNode } from "typescript";

type InventoryState = {
  inventoryItems: InventoryModel[];
};

const Inventory: React.FC = () => {
  const [inventory, setInventory] = useState<Partial<InventoryState>>({});
  useEffect(() => {
    const inventoryService = new InventoryService();
    const results = inventoryService.getByLocation().then((response) => {
      setInventory({ ...inventory, inventoryItems: response });
    });
  }, []);
  return <div></div>
```

"inventoryItems" is what is highlighted red in this case.

Comment: The compiler might give you a more actionable error if you change the `(response)` parameter to `(response: InventoryModel[])`

Comment: Thanks that helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out i just needed to add | void to InventoryState.

```
type InventoryState = {
  inventoryItems: InventoryModel[] | void;
};
```